# Can istio rewrite HTTLS/TLS traffic?

Tags: istio

According to their documentation of [TLSRoute](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#TLSRoute) it does not include rewrite that you typically do for [HTTPRoute`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute)

Is it possible to do the same for HTTPS or TLS ?

```
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /ratings
    rewrite:
      uri: /v1/bookRatings
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When TLS traffic is not terminated, traffic (including the URL parts needed for rewrite) is encrypted and therefore Istio can't read or manipulate it. Therefore, these options are not available.

Comment: So there should be some terminate option right /s

Comment: Yes, but this is done at a Gateway. See https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress